# Finding $1+\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}+ \frac{\sin^2x}{\sin 2x}+...+\frac{\sin^2x}{\sin 2x}$ using this method.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$1+\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}+ \frac{\sin^2x}{\sin 2x}+...+\frac{\sin^nx}{\sin nx}$$
The assignment on the first part of the question was done by using the the fact that for a complex number $z$, this is true: $$1+z+...+z^n = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}, z\neq 1$$ and so $$|1+z+...+z^n|^2 = \frac{|z^{n+1}-1|^2}{|z-1|^2}, z\neq 1$$ The left side was then represented as the product of the complex number and it's conjugate.. I am told the same idea is to be used in solving this problem, just having  $$z= \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} + \frac{\sin x}{\sin x}i$$
 Trying this out, did not pan out for me too well. Anyone see how this is to be done?